# jquery: Why do opacity animations only work with FF?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I'm wondering why opacity animations only work with Firefox, and not with chrome or internet explorer.

For example,

```
jQuery("#a").fadeTo(1000,1);
```

fades the element in with firefox, but just makes it appear with Chrome or IE. All I want is for the element to fade in.

How can I get this to work with IE and chrome?

Edit: Same thing if I use fadeIn() or any other similar function, like show()

---

Edit: I ended up fixing the issue. I will post back later with details; it had to do with nested elements. Just wanted to post this edit so no one wastes their time trying to answser :)

Thanks to all that answered!

---

Edit: Turns out the problem was that `#a` (which is an `<a href.../>`) has a div within it - *inside the div* is the image and text I wanted to fade. Instead of fading `#a`, I did:

```
$("#a").find("div").fadeTo...
```

(which worked perfectly).

Anyways thanks again for the answers; I've selected the one that was most helpful as accepted.

Comment: A value of 1 to opacity property should make the element appear and not fade out. Are you sure this is how it works in FF?

Comment: Can you post a bigger snippet of code? It's hard to tell what the problem is from just the one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this quick demo of .fadeIn and .fadeTo, and verify it in your browsers: http://www.jsfiddle.net/w3bt8/1/

What kind of element are you fading?  Also, are you using $(document).ready() correctly?

Answer (score 2):

There should be something wrong in your code. The fadeIn and fadeOut work in all browsers. JQuery team has really worked hart to do all that stuff :)

Answer (score 1):

The fading functions of jQuery should work in all current browsers. In IE, they look ugly because of crappy anti-aliasing but they work.